# Tree structure for comparing trees among each other

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, comparison, treenode

I'm looking for a tree, which would best fit in for my use case. The tree should contain elements of type *Hardware*, which is including the variable *ElementType*:

```
enum ElementType{
    Microcontroller;
    Core;
    Memory;
    Sensor;
    Pin;
    Network;
}
```

The nodes should be named after the *ElementType* of the Hardware element:

[image]

Once I've build up several trees (like the one above), I want to compare them to each other and check if one tree is part of an other tree. E.g. the the tree above should be compared to the following tree and as a result it should give me back, that the first tree is part of the second one. The trees should be compared through their node name (*ElementType*), as the underlying objects differs among each tree:

[image]

Is there any tree strucutre in java, which would fit in for my requirements?

Answer (score 1):

There's not, to my knowledge a structure but it's pretty easy to implement

```
public class Tree {
   private Node root;

   public boolean containsSubTree(Tree other) {
      return root.containsSubTree(other.root);
   }
}

public class Node {
  private Node parent;
  private ElementType elementType;
  private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();

  public Node(Node parent, ElementType elementType) {
     ...
  }

  public void addChild(Node child) {
     children.add(child);
  }

  protected boolean equalsIgnoreParent(Node other) {
     if (elementType != other.elementType) return false;
     if (children.size() != other.children.size()) return false;
     for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); ++ i) {
        // recursive step
        if (!children.get(i).equalsIgnoreParent(other.children.get(i)) {
           return false;
        }
     }
     return true;
  }

  public boolean containsSubTree(Node other) {
     if (equalsIgnoreParent(other)) return true;
     for (Node child : children) {
        // recursive step
        if (child.containsSubTree(other)) return true;
     }
     return false;
  }
}
```

And then just call tree1.containsSubTree(tree2) to check.

If you want to ignore the ordering of the children, you'd probably store the children as a [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) which would require an appropriate [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

My solution is implemented using [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) which can result in deep [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). I'm sure it could be implemented without recursion.... I just can't be bothered :)

Comment: Thx for this! I'll test it later and let zou know :)

Comment: Ok, the first part with the tree structure works fine so far. But the comparism algorithm doesn't work. I tried it with the example above, but it gave me a "false" back, which is not right, as all subTrees of the first tree are contained in the second tree. In your "equalsIgnoreParent" method for examples, the size of the child elements will be checked, which is not right. I tried now for a few hours to provide my own solution, but it's pretty hard.

Comment: Ah, I obviously didn't fully understand your problem. My ```equalsIgnoreParent``` method checks if the two nodes are exactly the same (ignoring the parent). You'll need to tweak it to check if all of the ```other``` node's elements are present in ```this``` node (and at the same depth). It's a bit trickier but can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I got the wrong idea in my other answer. Here's another attempt:

```
public class Node {
   // LinkedHashMap preserves order in which nodes were added
   private Map<ElementType, Node> childMap = new LinkedHashMap<ElementType, Node>();
   private ElementType elementType;

   public void addChild(Node node) {
      if (childMap.containsKey(node.elementType)) {
         throw new IllegalStateException("Duplicates not allowed");
      }
      childMap.put(node.elementType, node);
   }

   public Collection<Node> getChildren() {
      return childMap.values(); 
   }

   /**
    * Ensure all nodes in other are in this node.
    * Ignore any extra elements in this that are not in other
    */
   protected boolean isSameIgnoreExtras(Node other) {
      if (this.elementType != other.elementType) return false;
      if (this.childMap.size() < other.childMap.size()) return false;

      for (Node otherChild : other.getChildren()) {
         Node thisChild = childMap.get(otherChild.elementType);
         if (thisChild == null) {
            return false;
         }
         // recursive step
         if (!thisChild.isSameIgnoreExtras(otherChild)) {
            return false;
         }
      }
      return true;
   }

   public boolean containsSubTree(Node other) {
      if (isSameIgnoreExtras(other)) {
         return true;
      }
      for (Node child : getChildren()) {
         // recursive step
         if (child.containsSubTree(other)) {
            return true;
         }
      }
      return false;
   } 
}
```